# COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL after updating to Windows 10 build 17134

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

In my Xamarin.Forms project (currently supporting only UWP) we have a platform specific code that claims a Barcode scanner. This logic was working fine when the solution was run on my "LocalMachine" on Windows 10 build **16299**. After updating to Windows 10 build **17134** every time it crashes with the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'
Error code (0x80004005)
```

That exception is raised from the await **EnableScanner()** line bellow:

```
 private async void Initialize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // create the barcode scanner. 
        if (await CreateDefaultScannerObject())
        {
            // after successful creation, claim the scanner for exclusive use and enable it so that data reveived events are received.
            if (await ClaimScanner())
            {
                claimedScanner.ReleaseDeviceRequested += claimedScanner_ReleaseDeviceRequested;

                // after successfully claiming, attach the datareceived event handler.
                claimedScanner.DataReceived += claimedScanner_DataReceived;
                UpdateOutput(ScanningLang.DataReceivedAttached);

                claimedScanner.IsDecodeDataEnabled = true;

                if (await EnableScanner())
                    UpdateOutput(ScanningLang.ScanReady);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateOutput(ScanningLang.NoBarcodeScanner);
        }
    }
```

EnableScanner method:

```
 private async Task<bool> EnableScanner()
    {
        if (claimedScanner == null)
            return false;

        await claimedScanner.EnableAsync();
        UpdateOutput(ScanningLang.EnabledBarcodeSuccess);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: E_FAIL is but a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting in UWP, it is useless to diagnose the cause of the mishap.  Fairly unclear where CreateDefaultScannerObject() might come from, I'll assume it is a copy/paste of [this MSDN sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.getdefaultasync#Windows_Devices_PointOfService_BarcodeScanner_GetDefaultAsync).  Which is not flawless, it assumes there is a default device and you could easily have lost it with the upgrade.

Comment: So start by enumerating devices to ensure one is available.  And enable unmanaged debugging so you can see the underlying native C++ exception, it might have a breadcrumb.  Consider contacting the barcode scanner manufacturer for any known issues with this Windows version.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the suggestions! Will try the above-mentioned 2 suggestions and hopefully that will give me enough to find out what is going on.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: @tipa no, I have not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev I think I have solved my issue. The wrong device was returned for BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync so I had to search for the right device manually (and make sure that the VideoId is not null)

Comment: @tipa Thanks for the update. Could you please elaborate what you mean by the "wrong" device?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev What I mean with that is that this method returns a device without the VideoId property set - which indicates for me that it isnt the camera hardware device that we are looking for. Try out this class to get the device, it should work better: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/SharedContent/cs/DeviceHelpers.cs

Comment: @tipa Thanks for the suggestion. Will try it out.